# Webservice to Mainframe with WSDL name generated

Tags: web-services, wsdl, mainframe

When i create a web service to a mainframe(IBM) with WSDL  does the names on the service are supposed to match the ones on the copybook?

I just create a service and i have been unable to match properties on the web services with the fields on the copybook

If they are not the same how can i do the match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you're talking about [CICS Web Services](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/topics/dfhws_startHere.html).

> When i create a web service to a mainframe(IBM) with WSDL does the
>   names on the service are supposed to match the ones on the copybook?

Short answer: No.

If you generate copybooks from WSDL it is possible the field names are not valid variable names in the source language for which you are generating copybooks.

If you generate WSDL from copybooks it is possible the field names in the source language are not valid XML field names.

In either case, the generated copybooks have comments indicating which fields in the copybook correspond to which fields in the WSDL.